# Python insert on select with mysql

Tags: python, mysql

how to execute query `INSERT INTO DRAW (idcliente, date draw, stage)
SELECT id client, now () AS date_sorteo, 'S1' AS stage FROM client ORDER BY rand () LIMIT 4`of mysql from python

I have searched in google but it is only possible to do this by executing the insert and select separately

I am very new to python.

this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import errorcode


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="xx.xx.xx.xx",
  user="xxx",
  passwd="xxxx",
  database="xxx"
)

dbh = mydb.cursor()

dbh.execute("select count(idcliente) as total from cliente")
salida = dbh.fetchone()
for x in salida:
  print (x)

x=x/2

SQL="INSERT INTO SORTEO (idcliente, fecha_sorteo,etapa) SELECT idcliente,now() AS fecha_sorteo,'S1' AS etapa FROM cliente ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4 "

#print SQL


salida = dbh.execute(SQL)
dbh.commit()

print (salida)
```

Comment: What do you want the statement to do? `FROM courses rand() limit 10` doesn't have a SQL meaning.  Looking at the [INSERT .. SELECT manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) will show you the syntax. What troubles are you having? Which MySQL python implementation are you using?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Possibly you missing the `values` in the query.

Comment: I want to know how I do it in python for  `INSERT on SELECT ` query mysql

Comment: What is "it"? What python implementation (common are PyMySQL and [MySQL Python/Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/)? Describe your progress. What unexpected results are you getting? And what your invalid SQL is meant to do. We're not going to code it for you. This is a help site, not a free coding site.